# Systemd/ssh: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: ssh, systemd

I have a host (Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS 64 bit, kernel 3.13.0-85-generic) that has a lot of concurrent SSH connections. SSH logins have started to fail recently, and the log says:

```
sshd[26057]: pam_systemd(sshd:session): Failed to create session: Cannot allocate memory
```

I cannot figure out even which subsystem is enforcing that limit. The machine itself has 4 GB free RAM and 0 bytes of swap in use (of 8GB):

[image]

I wrote a small C program that mallocs a gig of RAM, which it does without issue, so it's not a system RAM thing.

I examined the `ulimit` settings, and looked at `/proc/<pid>/limits` to find out if there are OS limits defined, but all is unlimited.

I also looked into [systemd's resource limiting](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html), like the `MemoryLimit` parameter in `/etc/systemd/system/sshd.service`.

Nothing seems to have any effect. Any idea where this memory limit comes from?

Edit:

it is weird that systemd is installed, actually. These are the systemd packages:

```
# aptitude search systemd|grep "^i"
i A libpam-systemd                  - system and service manager - PAM module   
i A libsystemd-daemon0              - systemd utility library                   
i A libsystemd-login0               - systemd login utility library             
i A systemd-services                - systemd runtime services                  
i A systemd-shim                    - shim for systemd
```

It's version 204-5ubuntu20.19.

`apt-cache rdepends` is not really giving me a clear idea why it's installed. It's also not fully installed. The `systemctl` command is not available, for one.

Edit2: The systemd components seem to be included because of dbus. If I try to install dbus on another 14.04 system, it indeeds wants to pull in systemd.

Comment: What's all this about systemd? How did it get onto your system?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 with systemd? What `systemd` version is there?

Comment: @Jakuje it's indeed weird that systemd is there. I updated the post.

Comment: My understanding, however, is that unless the `systemd-sysv` package is also installed it does not replace `upstart`

Comment: `pam_systemd` should be NOP if you are not using systemd as init system according to `man pam_systemd`. Does it work if you remove/comment `pam_systemd` from `/etc/pam.d/common-session` or where does it come from?

Comment: @Jakuje that seems to have fixed it, but until I upgrade, I guess... It also appeared I needed to tweak the `MaxStartUps` parameter in `sshd_config`.

Comment: `MaxStartUps` option should drop the connection even before going into the PAM stack. You would see messages like `drop connection #N` if you would activate `LogLevel DEBUG`. But yes, it is needed for high-traffic `ssh` servers. These are config files and should not be overwritten unless you explicitly allow it. We have `authconfig-tui` to modify them (not sure about Ubuntu alternative).